# How to redirect to previous page in custom DeleteView?

Tags: python, django

I have the following custom `DeleteView`:

```
class CarDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Car
    context_object_name = 'car'
    template_name = 'cars/car_confirm_delete.html'
    success_message = "%(name)s is pending removal"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('car-list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
       name = self.object.name
        owner = self.object.owner
        if owner != self.request.user:
            messages.error(request, f'You don\'t have permissions to remove {name}')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

        # DO Stuff
        return redirect(reverse('car-list'))
```

I'm trying to redirect to previous entry point when user isn't the owner (so he can't delete). But `HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))` gives me the URL of the current page (`car_confirm_delete.html`) and not the previous one. How can I make it go to previous one? Maybe that's because Django does POST?

Comment: You could maybe incorporate some hidden input in your form which would contain the "next" address (as does the login form) and when this one is missing, just redirect them to that page. 

The HTTP_REFERER should afaik return the URI where was the form. (it's the delete confirm form view usually). So it would be a `HTTP_REFERER_REFERER` in your case, if you want to get to the previous page (before the user moved to the form)

I think this really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import HttpResponseRedirect

> from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

and then

> return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

Comment: That's not it. I do import it. Otherwise I would get an error not the url of the current page.